# INVALID IMAGE DATA WHILE USING FLUTTER_MAP

Tags: flutter

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: acquireCurrentLocation(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<LatLng?> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            print(snapshot.data!.latitude);
            return FlutterMap(
              options: MapOptions(
                center:
                    LatLng(snapshot.data!.latitude, snapshot.data!.longitude),
                zoom: 13.0,
              ),
              layers: [
                TileLayerOptions(
                    urlTemplate:
                        "cc",
                    additionalOptions: {
                      'accessToken':
                          'cc',
                      'id': 'cc',
                    }),
                MarkerLayerOptions(
                  markers: [
                    Marker(
                      width: 80.0,
                      height: 80.0,
                      point: LatLng(
                          snapshot.data!.latitude, snapshot.data!.longitude),
                      builder: (ctx) => Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                          onPressed: null,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting the error Invalid Image Data, I have input the correct token, URL in my working file.
Can Someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I can solve the error? I have tried running it in emulator as well as Real device, the error on debugging was shown in the painter.dart file in the most likely Future function declaration when(error!=null)

Comment: Please go easy on caps in the title. Can you post the full error output?

Comment: I/flutter (12257): LatLng(latitude:37.421998, longitude:-122.084)
I/flutter (12257): 37.4219983
I/flutter (12257): Exception: Invalid image data
I/chatty  (12257): uid=10087(explr.com.example.mappy) 1.ui identical 8 lines
I/flutter (12257): Exception: Invalid image data

Comment: Can you please provide the URL template? You don't have to reveal any API keys.

Comment: Hi, you'll probably want to delete that comment, it has your private key in it.

Comment: But, I can see that this is wrong. It's returning an XML file. When exporting, try exporting as 'Carto' and use that template URL, with the API key as additional options.

Comment: Sure Ill write it as an answer, please tick it if you dont mind :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of exporting as whatever you were doing, try exporting it as 'Carto', and then using that template they give you as the `urlTemplate`, and the private key as the `additionalOptions`. This is the format used by `flutter_map`.